# How to add user attributes to registration form in Keycloak?

Tags: authentication, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I've created a new realm (out of the box and using user account for login/registration) in Keycloak and enabled the user profile, added a new attribute - shop

[image]

The user attribute
[image]

Because this attribute is required, I want it to be in the default registration form

[image]

Is this possible to do?

It will be nice to have the user attributes in the JWT token as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a field to the registration form by adding a [custom theme](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes) (You might do it by overriding the main theme, but they don't recommend overriding the main theme).

Add a custom theme in the themes folder.

Customize your `./themes/custom-theme/login/register.ftl` file to add a custom field like the below:
(Please follow the [link](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-user-registration#custom-attrs))

```html
<div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
                <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
                    <label for="user.attributes.dob" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">
                    Date of birth</label>
                </div>

                <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
                    <input type="date" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" 
                    id="user.attributes.dob" name="user.attributes.dob" 
                    value="${(register.formData['user.attributes.dob']!'')}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Then the dob will be added as user attributes after a successful registration.

Comment: Thanks! that's the only way to do it?

Comment: If you want to get user input then it's the only way. Otherwise, you can add attributes manually.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it possible to make the attributes is unique (just like the user name), so each user will have a unique `shop`? I can see the validator for attributes can do email, names and numbers etc, but not for uniqueness in the whole users

Comment: If my Keycloak is running in a docker container, is it possilbe to change the register.ftl file in the container?

Comment: Yes. it's possible. All you have to do is mount your custom theme folder to the docker container volumes